# .htaccess for subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following structure

```
-www
  \-subfolder
```

In `www` I have my main site's `index.php`.

In subfolder I have a sort of admin UI and in there I'd like to have another `index.php` for the admin UI.

Currently my requests from within `/subfolder/index.php` get redirected to `www/index.php` and basically the pages of my admin UI don't show up.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Can you help me? I've tried several options in other answers but as I'm no so advanced a web developer, I couldn't get any to work.

---

@TerryE, Sorry if I have come off as crude.

I am using a local setup for testing. 
I have installed Vertrigo server, which gives me Apache server.Running on Windows7 OS. The server is installed in Program files\VertrigoServ\Apache folder.

My public folder is www. In there I have my main  site definition.  . The site is accessed locally via `127.0.0.1/index.php` or `127.0.0.1/`

I have site localization so URLs are constructed as `/$lang/$page`  e.g. `<a href=" / <?php echo $lang; ?> / home "> HOME </a>`

In `index.php` of main site I have the following:

```
$page = trim( ( isset( $_GET[ 'page' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'page' ] : 'home' ), '/' );

$lang = trim( ( isset( $_GET[ 'lang' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'lang' ] : 'en' ), '/' );
$langs = array( 'en', 'fr', 'ru' );
```

And upon this data I get to open the pages this way:

```
include 'html/'. $lang . '/' . $page . '.php';
```

All my main site's pages lie in `www/html/$lang/`

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` gives `/en/home` for page HOME.

`127.0.0.1/en/home` WORKS

### All navigation works perfectly for the main site.

However I have created an admin UI which lies in folder www/admin - one level below in www.

And in there I don't have any localization. I just have EN as language. 
So at the top of the index.php in admin folder I have again

```
$page = trim( ( isset( $_GET[ 'page' ] ) ? $_GET[ 'page' ] : 'home' ), '/' );
```

However, here navigation is as follows `<a href=/admin/home"> HOME </a>`

and upon this I get to construct the pages in the index.php in admin folder as follows:

```
include 'html/ . $page . '.php';
```

the pages lie in `www/admin/html`

This does not work at all. Whenever I press home link in admin UI, I get redirected to my main site (non-existing page).  If I add `RewriteRule ^subfolder/ - [L]` in .htaccess, I get `HTTP 404 NOT Found error`.

`127.0.0.1/admin/home` DOES NOT WORK. Neither does any other navigation from within admin. Thank you for your willingness and patience to help me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume from this that you only have a single **.htaccess** file in your **www** directory.

Think about what the rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

does when interpreted in a Perdir context from **www**: take any URI of the form `someDir/somePage` and replace it by `index.php?lang=someDir&page=somePage`, so this will intercept and rewrite any `/subfolder/index.php`.

This isn't well documented but Perdir processing will preferentially use the lowest **.htaccess** file setting `RewriteEngine On` on the request path.  So if you add an admin-specific **.htaccess** file in the "subfolder" subfolder, this will preempt the **www** one and circumvent this problem.

### Postscript comments

Veni and other posters get in a Q&A when the real issue is one of "how do I debug my .htaccess rules if I my website is hosted by a shared service?" The reason that I add the shared service qualification is that if you have root access to your LAMP config then you can turn on Rewrite logging and the logfile at a debug level of 4-6 will give you enough forensics to work out what is going on.

However, the large majority of hobby / small service users buy their services on a shared basis and here they don't have root access and the hosting provider disables such logging for performance reasons so they have a binary feedback -- the rules work or they don't.  I use a shared service and my approach (described [here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-61)) is to set up a VM which mirrors this configuration for as a test and integration environment -- and in this I have such root access. However, this is probably far too complicated for most users.  This is really a wider topic that merits its own Q / discussion.

On specific points:

- If your structure is `/(lang|admin)/page`, then why do you have this rule because it can cause havoc on perdir retries.

  ```
  RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
  ```
- Better something like the following to force a redirect to a default language (assume the lang list is EN and IT in this example:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  RewriteCond $1 !^/(en|it|admin)/
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://yourdomain/en/$1 [R=301,L]
  ```
- Are you aware of the redirect restart /looping issues? (search for REDIRECT_STATUS)

I'm new to Stackoverflow, but not to sorting out this sort of s**t.  I've got a couple of detailed articles on my blog on this.

### Postscript comments -- yet more

OK some general help.

- Don't us fixed IPs put an alias for 127.0.0.1 in your windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
- You can turn on rewrite logging in your VertrigoServ Apache config and this gives you a detailed audit of where you have problems
- It also helps if you have a little diagnostic stub to help you understand what is going on  and this is what I came up with for index.php in the test directories:

  ```
  <?php header( "Content-type: text.plain" ); echo "main: "; var_export($_GET);
  ```

But you really need for each of the following cases:
 -  to handle the URI exists (and stop rewrite loops)
 -  the defaults for / and /admin/
 -  admin/*
 -  */*
 -  * (and the language defaults)

and this is what I came up with.  I've kept it simple.  We could use complex regexps to fold some of these but why bother.  You may need to add more QSAs if needed.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f                [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .  -                                  [L]

RewriteRule ^$ index.php                          [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/index.php             [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php?page=$1  [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=en&page=$1      [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your assumption is correct, I have only one htaccess file in my www folder. What should be the contents in the htcaccess file in my subfolder then?

Comment: @Veni, The perdir processing will select the `subfolder/.htaccess` file if it exists and RewriteEngine on.  If you've go no rewrites to do then you don't need any.  This just means that the root access file isn't processed for subfolder URIs

Comment: my main site's url structure is domainname.com/lang/page E.g. www.domainname.com/en/home; and the structure of the admin UI is domainname.com/subfolder/page. I don't seem to get it to work. Obviously I am missing something. Could you please help me further? Thank you!

Comment: @Veni, I'll update my reply above in a minute.  Look for changes :-)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing your philosophical point of view but unfortunately you're not really helping...What you have written just confuses me more. I have a specific problem in an area I am not an expert in and need a solution. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @Veni, you want specific help but are providing a generalised version of your problem.  I would like to help but I am not clairvoyant. Give me a specific URI that works and one that doesn't.  Also the obvious stuff:  Does Apache run in a different UID to your app files.  If so have you set the world permissions on your directories / files / .htaccess so that Apache sees them?

Comment: @Venia, See latest changes.  Tested and does what you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ subfolder/index.php?page=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I used what you suggested in .htaccess in www folder, and now the links don't lead to the main site, but whatever link I click in the subfolder e.g. domainname.com/subfolder/page gives me HTTP 404 NOT Found. Do I possibly need a separate htaccess for the subfolder?

Answer (score -1):

You could prevent requests to you subfolder from being rewritten with the change below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]

#prevent requests to your subfolder from being rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The subfolder does not get rewritten but I am getting HTTP 404 Not found exception. my links are constructed as /subfolder/page and in subfolder index.php I have include include 'html/'. $apage.'.php'; where the html folder is inside the subfolder. I appreciate your help!