# htaccess rewrite rule for subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess for subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805464/htaccess-for-subfolder)

My site structure is

-www
  -subfolder
In www I have my main site's index.php.

In subfolder I have a sort of admin UI and in there I have another index.php for the admin UI.

Currently my requests from within /subfolder/index.php get redirected to www/index.php and basically the pages of my admin UI don't show up.

### This is my .htaccess file in www folder:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

---

For main site I have url structure: www.domainname.com/lang/page E.g. www.domainname.com/en/home

and For Admin site in subfolder I have url structure www.domainname.com/subfolder/page

How do I get the pages in subfolder to display? Do I need anoother htaccess in the subfolder? With what contents? Please help me sort it out. I've tried many examples listed in other answers to no avail. It will save me tons of work!